# OpenLayers: how to change format of MousePosition coordinates to HDMS?

Tags: coordinates, gis, openlayers, format-string

I'm using the MousePosition control to show the mouse coordinates as it moves but I'm showing an output similar to this: '7.85, 47.98' but I wanted an output like this: '47° 58′ 60.0″ N 7° 50′ 60.0 " E'.

JS

```
var mouseposition = new ol.control.MousePosition({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(2),
            undefinedHTML: '',
            className: 'ol-mouse-position ol-control'
        });
        map.addControl(mouseposition);
```

I've tried to use toStringHDMS() but it wasn't in the format I wanted, I don't know if I used it wrong

```
var mouseposition = new ol.control.MousePosition({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(),
            undefinedHTML: '',
            className: 'ol-mouse-position ol-control'
        });
        map.addControl(mouseposition);
```

n this example the output was: -46.20849609375,-23.595295498937958

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS,
```

without `()`.

`createStringXY()` is a function which returns a CoordinateFormat function

`toStringHDMS` is already a CoordinateFormat function